# Prestashop partial order invoincing

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I would like to know if it is possible to invoice only a part of a client order. I don't want to change the original order of the client. I need to invoice only that articles that I have in my stock. My environment is with no stock.

Answer (score 0):

You can override PDF class, but order total will be different than invoice total and you should add an invoiced total column in AdminOrders vieworder for your info.
I do not see the point about allow orders with no stock products, then not include these in bill but not delete products in order ....

Prestashop statistics will be affected too.

I am not on your shoes, but I advise you to analyze the situation and take the simplest solution.